# Jhipster In production mode unable to call apis from localhost as in dev mode

Tags: java, jhipster

I am using jhipster for my application. when I run ./mvnw with default dev profile I can call call apis from Postman using `localhost:8080` but when I run ./mvnw -P prod ,project runs but I am unable to call APIs with production profile. when I used `localhost:8080` for API call it did not work. So How I can call APIs for production profile ? I just want to test my yml setting in Production profile. When I used

`./mvnw` , So default profile `dev` is working and I call API from postman using localhost but when I run `./mvnw -P prod` it shows running active profile is `production` but when I call APIs from postman using localhost it shows unreachable server. So My question is when we run in production mode How we can test apis because localhost not working.

Comment: @ Gaël Marziou- unable to call http://localhost:8080/api/get and server logs show active profile is prod

Comment: @Gaël Marziou - question edited

Comment: Thanks but you did not answer about swagger-ui and https. Also are you able to use the UI of your app in browser? Have you checked the "Access URLs" logged by server?

Comment: @Gaël Marziou - `./mvnw -P prod` last message in logs is `Web application configuration, using profiles: prod` It did not show on which URL I can access APIs. I tried `Swagger-ui` and `https` using `localhost:8080` but it shows unable to connect.

Comment: This is very strange because the logging of access urls is in the `main()` of your application and it's an old feature, see example here: https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app/blob/main/src/main/java/io/github/jhipster/sample/JhipsterSampleApplicationApp.java#L86-L101  Did you modify it? Or did you generate your app using a  very old version of JHipster. I suggest you have a look at your main() and if it's different you consider copying code from sample app.